# Tableau - Optimal table structure for sports

Tags: data-structures, data-visualization, tableau-api

I am trying make a table structure to analyze (for example) table tennis games in tableau. I was thinking about a data table structure like this:

| ID | Date | Game | Set | Player | Points | Win/Loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12/19/20 | 1 | 1 | Tom | 11 | Win |
| 2 | 12/19/20 | 1 | 1 | Mark | 8 | Loss |

I want to be able to analyze the stats of every player but also want to be able to compare different players against each other. It should also be able to input 2 vs 2 player games.

Is this the optimal way for the table structure?
I have seen other tables for sports where each row is one match. So I was wondering if it would be better to put one game or one set per row instead?

Comment: There are often good reasons for recording match results *twice* in such tables, once for each player. This makes analysis *by player* much easier. If it were football, for example, I would have one column for each team with another column for the home or away status. The match result would appear twice in the table but team comparisons would be much easier. same here.

Comment: Thank you, so this should be fine then.

Comment: Yes. Depending on the analysis you want to do, though, it can be worth adding both players to each row and/or including a unique ID for each match/game/round or whatever is useful. In soccer, I include the home team in one column and the away team in another to ease some analyses.

Comment: Thank you. I will try both then and see what gets the best results.